# Selenium Webdriver error related to the Windows.Fetch for the login

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, fetch-api

I'm trying to login by building up the URL using the following:

Chrome Login:

```
URL = "https://" + Username + ":" + Password + "@" + TestShortURL;
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(URL);
```

On of the application Pop-ups an error is being displayed:

```
Error getting experiment details from server: TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request cannot be constructed from a URL that includes credentials
```

The developer has confirmed that the authentication details are being used in the other pages, this was working before but now the JavaScript fetch API is being used for AJAX calls. The encrypted windows user credentials information is being sent with each request (as, the option {credentials: "include"} is being used.

Is there a way I can login into the application and not include the details on other pages. Thanks